# Camera view not aligning with camera? Blender 2.82

Tags: camera

When I try to use either the camera button or <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> the camera snaps to the object instead of the actual camera?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> assigns any active object as current camera.

To set your camera the current camera, select it and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

Now <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> will use the camera.